# chart.js: set specific numbers in y-axis

Tags: chart.js

I'm using chart.js version: 2.9.3

My line graph has 16,000 points.
The Y value range is from 10E7 ti -10E7
I want to display 10E7, -10E7 on the Y-axis and not 10000000, -10000000
How can I do it ?

Thank you in advance,
Zvika

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ticks.callback` property in `options.scales.yAxes` along with Javascript's [Number.toExponential](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential).

For example:

```js
{
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Data',
      data: [93000, -292768, -172234, -836236, 743553, 95348, 453460],
      fill: false,
    }, ],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          callback: function(val) {
            return val.toExponential()
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  },
}
```

[image: chart.js with scientific notation]

Comment: Thank you very much !